# Require field validation is not working while adding other JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have web page which has three view and on the second view I want to validate one JavaScript function. If I don't add this function then the require field validation is working fine while I add this JavaScript function, and try to call on the page load require field validation is no working.

```
function checkDate()
    {           
        var dt = new Date();
        var month =1 + dt.getMonth();
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var e = document.getElementById("<%=PurchMonth.ClientID%>");
        var monthvalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var e1 = document.getElementById("<%=PurchDay.ClientID%>");
        var dayvalue = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;

        if (monthvalue < month)
        {                  
           return true;
        }
        else if (monthvalue ==month )
        {
            if (dayvalue>day)
            {
                alert("Future Date is not allowed");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else                
        {
            alert("Future Date is not allowed");
            return false;
        }
    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnModelsNext.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return checkDate();");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed Following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnModelsNext.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Validate();");
    }
```

and the JavaScript would be as following

```
function Validate() {
        if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
            return checkDate();
        }
        return false;
    }

    function checkDate()
    {  rest of the code
        }
```